# How can I answer SIP calls from Asterisk.NET C# Library...

Tags: c#, sip, voip, asterisk

I am designing a simple call application using Asterisk.NET C# Library. 
What I want to do is to... 
1. Notify When a call is coming to any extensions.
2. Answering calls that are coming to my extensions.
and Put it in Speaker Mode
3. Hangup the Call.

I could connect and hangup the call, but not answer or putting it in speaker mode...
Please Help....

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you read this topics:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI